# filter some records by type and date with postgres

Tags: postgresql

i need help to prepare a query that resolve this question:

doing: **select * from clients**

```
id | client_name | client_type | reg_date
11 | Abdul       | 5           | 2019-03-02
44 | Miquel      | 2           | 2019-09-11
12 | Alex        | 5           | 2019-09-10
18 | Sam         | 3           | 2019-09-02
62 | Julio       | 2           | 2019-06-02
65 | Luis        | 3           | 2019-02-12
94 | Manu        | 3           | 2019-09-08
72 | Robert      | 2           | 2019-09-07
29 | Lisa        | 1           | 2019-09-02
12 | Alex        | 4           | 2019-09-10 
22 | Pedro       | 3           | 2019-09-10
24 | Mary        | 4           | 2019-09-11
24 | MariLuz     | 5           | 2019-09-01
29 | Lisa        | 5           | 2019-03-02
02 | Jorge       | 3           | 2019-09-01
18 | Sam         | 1           | 2019-09-03
88 | Omar        | 2           | 2019-02-12
32 | Jhon        | 3           | 2019-01-23
98 | Yona        | 4           | 2019-09-11
97 | Marisa      | 2           | 2019-09-05
96 | Juan        | 5           | 2019-03-02
95 | Carmen      | 3           | 2019-09-01
94 | Kike        | 1           | 2019-09-03
85 | Mario       | 2           | 2019-02-12
87 | Raul        | 5           | 2019-09-03
75 | Martina     | 5           | 2019-09-01
73 | Lara        | 5           | 2019-09-09
```

My question is:
how can i filter this result to see just the **first 4** clients that has **type 5** the **first 3** clients that have **type 3** and the **first 2** clients that has **type 2** and also was inserted on the actual month (09)

so the result must contain just:

```
id | client_name | client_type | reg_date
12 | Alex        | 5           | 2019-09-10
24 | MariLuz     | 5           | 2019-09-01
87 | Raul        | 5           | 2019-09-03
75 | Martina     | 5           | 2019-09-01
18 | Sam         | 3           | 2019-09-02
94 | Manu        | 3           | 2019-09-08
22 | Pedro       | 3           | 2019-09-10
44 | Miquel      | 2           | 2019-09-11
72 | Robert      | 2           | 2019-09-07
```

can somebody give an advice to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_type ORDER BY reg_date) rn
    FROM clients
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reg_date) = 9 AND
    client_type IN (2, 3, 5)
)

SELECT id, client_name, client_type, reg_date
FROM cte
WHERE
    (client_type = 2 AND rn <= 2) OR
    (client_type = 3 AND rn <= 3) OR
    (client_type = 4 AND rn <= 4)
ORDER BY
    client_type DESC;
```

If you only want records from 2019 alone, we can slightly modify the above query.

Comment: Sorry , but i was updating my question ... adding a filter that i forgot. So sorry can you help with this? Thanks

Comment: Your query fetches the whole table data (lets say it is full scan). Recursive CTE could be much more efficient (IMO).

Comment: @Abelisto Would an index on `(client_type, reg_date)` help the CTE?

Comment: Not sure but my opinion: no. Just check it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/75337/1 - I hope that this simple example will explain my point about filtering by results of window functions.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements:

```
(select * from clients where client_type = 5 and date_trunc('month', reg_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date) order by reg_date asc limit 4)
union all
(select * from clients where client_type = 3 and date_trunc('month', reg_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date) order by reg_date asc limit 3)
union all
(select * from clients where client_type = 2 and date_trunc('month', reg_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date) order by reg_date asc limit 2)
```

Note that the "first n" is related to the `reg_date` value.

Also to improve performance you will need to create functional index `on clients(date_trunc('month', reg_date))`
(additionally to index(es) on `client_type` and `reg_date`)